# Group partial class shortcut

Tags: visual-studio

I have to cs file for one partial class. I know that I can modify project file to group them together like way that vs.net group *.aspx and *.aspx.cs, but is there a way to do that in vs.net IDE directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is the plugin you are looking for:

http://mokosh.co.uk/vscommands/

Works in VS 2008 and 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [VSCommands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features) extension for Visual Studio 2012. Select files to group from Solution Explorer, Right click -> Group Items.

Answer (score 1):

Guy from Microsoft [says](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/13f1c0bd-641f-4040-8603-758d54bf77c7/) the only way is by editing the CSPROJ. Maybe an extension will pop up soon that does this.